# How big is the download for my users if my app requires the 2015 Android Vision API?

Tags: android, ios

I am interested in adding face detection to my app (com.google.android.gms.vision.face the Google Play services 7.8 version as described [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2015/08/face-detection-in-google-play-services.html) [here](https://developers.google.com/vision/?utm_campaign=facedetection-815&utm_source=dac&utm_medium=blog) and [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/package-summary))

But in the documentation it says 'Adding the vision functionality dependency to your project's AndroidManifest.xml will indicate to the installer that it should download the dependency on app install time'

Its very important to me that my App size should be small and not require a huge  download- so does anyone know how big the 'dependency' for com.google.android.gms.vision.face will be and how much it will add to my download for users that don't already have it?

Also do people know if iOS works the same way?

Answer (score 0):

Your app size always depends upon the artwork you have used to beautify your app interface, how detailed your application has been developed and how many dependency the application is using, sometime the application size is very small on app store, but after downloading the app on phone, the app installs dependency on run time and consume some disk space.This approach save developers to submit heavy applications to the store.

This can be true for both platforms i.e. iOS and Android. I am expert on iOS development so don't know about this specific dependency com.google.android.gms.vision.face. So any expert on Android might answer this. But I think it might not take so much memory as, it will not contains any images but few kbs of files.

Comment: Hi thanks for your thoughts... I have been converting some javascript face detectors to C# because anything that is based on OpenCV tends to be absolutely huge- generally 30meg or so at least, and thats not because of images, its just code... I don't know if Android/iOS face detection is based on OpenCV but whether it is or not, but I think its very likely that it will be a pretty big chunk of code, unless they have specifically tried to make it not so.

Comment: Do you know if iOS has face detection built in or if it adds it on demand like Android is?